# Excel Spreadsheet Slow to Calculate

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that is constantly 'calculating' causing very slow performance. I suspect it has to do with this formula -

```
=COUNTIFS('Current ACTIVE Reps'!D:D,[@[Paycom Location]],'Current ACTIVE Reps'!H:H,[@[Paycom Division]],'Current ACTIVE Reps'!K:K,"<"&[@[Week Beginning]])-COUNTIFS('Current ACTIVE Reps'!$D:$D,[@[Paycom Location]],'Current ACTIVE Reps'!H:H,[@[Paycom Division]],'Current ACTIVE Reps'!L:L,"<="&[@[Week Beginning]],'Current ACTIVE Reps'!L:L,">"&0)
```

Because the reference to 'Current ACTIVE Reps' is looking at the entire column. I was thinking of using a structured reference instead (for example - changing the 'Current ACTIVE Reps'!D:D, to be CurrentActiveReps[@[Location_Code]] but this is returning an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many volatile functions are you using: `INDIRECT()`,`OFFSET()`, `ADDRESS()`?  That is usually the problem.  Also, how big is the table in which this is placed, how many rows?  If we are talking less than 1000, it is probably not this formula.

Comment: If it turns out you really have to keep that formula, you can always change the workbook's calculation mode to Manual, and calculate formulas as needed. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-in-excel-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4

Comment: The sheet this formula is on is 7K rows. None of the sheets in the workbook have any volatile functions like -  INDIRECT(),OFFSET(), ADDRESS(). Appreciate the help! This one is confusing to me.